# How to throw a nice looking exception in API if BindingResults has Errors?

Tags: java, spring

Is the only way to do this is code like this that has to be repeated in every controller?

```
  if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
     List<FieldError> fieldErrorList = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
     AtomicReference<String> message = new AtomicReference<>("");

        fieldErrorList.stream()
                .forEach(fieldError -> message.set("Field name: " + fieldError.getField()
                        + " Rejected Value: " + fieldError.getRejectedValue()
                        + " Message " + fieldError.getDefaultMessage()));
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(message.get());
    }
```

Or maybe there is a better way to do it. I can not put this logic in Exception class as super(message) has to be the first line. I would appreciate if you could share your way of doing it.

Comment: Try using @ControllerAdvice. You can customize error responses to users as you wish and apply these customizations to all controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reading materials as such first:

1. https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc
2. https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

There you have a lot of ideas how you can handle exceptions for all controllers nicely ;-)

Consider using **@ControllerAdvice**. You can customize error responses to users as you wish and apply these customizations to all controllers.